# Multiple clicks doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to android, I made this simple app that adds 1 to a variable called clicks every time the user clicks the button. The first time I click the button it works perfectly, but when I click it other times it doesn't work at all.
Here's my code:
```

```
    val clicks = 0

    button.setOnClickListener() {
        tvn.setText("You clicked the button $clicks times.")
    }
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `val` but not `var` and that's why I couldn't change the value of the variable `clicks`

Answer (score 1):

suppose `clicks` is the private member of class

```
private int clicks = 0;

   ...............

 button.setOnClickListener() {

        clicks++;
        tvn.setText("You clicked the button times."+ clicks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping .. I knew why it didn't work

Comment: I was going to accept my own answer because it's clearer.